# jquery.final-countdown.js issue with displaying date circle

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown, jquery-countdown

I tried to follow below instructions to configure the plugin. http://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Modern-Circular-jQuery-Countdown-Timer-Plugin-Final-Countdown.html

I am facing little bit weird issue.
if start time and current time(now) are same day then i am not getting circle on days div. if i change the timestamp to other day then it is working fine.
I don't know why it is happening. Can anybody advise me what i am doing wrong.

here are some code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.countdown').final_countdown({
        'start': '1434872408',
        'end': '1436506200',
        'now': '1434877414'
    });
</script>
```

here is html code.

```
<div class="countdown countdown-container container">
    <div class="clock row">
        <div class="clock-item clock-days countdown-time-value col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="inner">
                    <div id="canvas-days" class="clock-canvas"></div>

                    <div class="text">
                        <p class="val">0</p>
                        <p class="type-days type-time">DAYS</p>
                    </div><!-- /.text -->
                </div><!-- /.inner -->
            </div><!-- /.wrap -->
        </div><!-- /.clock-item -->

        <div class="clock-item clock-hours countdown-time-value col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="inner">
                    <div id="canvas-hours" class="clock-canvas"></div>

                    <div class="text">
                        <p class="val">0</p>
                        <p class="type-hours type-time">HOURS</p>
                    </div><!-- /.text -->
                </div><!-- /.inner -->
            </div><!-- /.wrap -->
        </div><!-- /.clock-item -->

        <div class="clock-item clock-minutes countdown-time-value col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="inner">
                    <div id="canvas-minutes" class="clock-canvas"></div>

                    <div class="text">
                        <p class="val">0</p>
                        <p class="type-minutes type-time">MINUTES</p>
                    </div><!-- /.text -->
                </div><!-- /.inner -->
            </div><!-- /.wrap -->
        </div><!-- /.clock-item -->

        <div class="clock-item clock-seconds countdown-time-value col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="inner">
                    <div id="canvas-seconds" class="clock-canvas"></div>

                    <div class="text">
                        <p class="val">0</p>
                        <p class="type-seconds type-time">SECONDS</p>
                    </div><!-- /.text -->
                </div><!-- /.inner -->
            </div><!-- /.wrap -->
        </div><!-- /.clock-item -->
    </div><!-- /.clock -->
</div><!-- /.countdown-wrapper -->
```

Comment: `if start time and current time(now) are same day then i am not getting circle on days div` then days would be `0`, so why would there be a circle on the days div?

Comment: thanks for your comment. can you explain why not?

Comment: ... because there are no days to show on the countdown

Comment: So, it means i don't need to do anything. Everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28847577/jquery-final-countdown-js-need-help-configuring-it). You just need to configure

- `start` value,
- `end` value,
- `target` value

of countdown clock.

Default configure show same value, so you need to make different value.

Hope it help